# Crosscompile for OpenWRT with c++11 flag

Tags: c++, c++11, openwrt

I am new in OpenWRT and I need to crosscompile c++ program. The problem is, I am still getting this error:

```
error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
  "duplicate raw value " + std::to_string(it->first));
                           ^
```

Now I know, it's problem, that there isn't used c++11 flag during compilation. I tried to add TARGET_CXXFLAGS into Makefile, but it didn't help me.

Here is the Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=gateway
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=2
INIT_SCRIPT_NAME:=$(PKG_NAME)

PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION).tar.xz
PKG_SOURCE_SUBDIR:=$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(PKG_VERSION)
PKG_SOURCE_PROTO:=git
PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS:=+libmosquittopp +poco +zmq +cppzmq +openzwave +cppunit +bluez-libs
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=....
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=...

CMAKE_INSTALL:=1

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/cmake.mk

CMAKE_OPTIONS += \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/ \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

TARGET_CXXFLAGS += -DPOCO_NO_FPENVIRONMENT 
TARGET_CXXFLAGS += -g -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic

....
```

Thank you for your advice, Jakub.

Comment: What standard library (including version) are you using? If it's old enough, it might not have `to_string` in it. In that case, changing the Makefile won't help.

Comment: You mean version of g++? I am using g++ version 5.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on GCC version and STD lib version. I can confirm that the last version from upstream works perfectly. Here is my *test* Makefile which may help you and give you some clues.

```
CXX=/media/build/openwrt/staging_dir/toolchain-arm_cortex-a7+neon-vfpv4_gcc-5.5.0_musl_eabi/bin/arm-openwrt-linux-g++

RM=rm -f
LDLIBS=
CPPFLAGS=-Wall -std=c++11
LDFLAGS=-L/media/build/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a7+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/usr/lib
INC=-I. -I/media/build/openwrt/staging_dir/target-arm_cortex-a7+neon-vfpv4_musl_eabi/usr/include


SOURCES=main.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = hello

all: $(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) $(INC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)

distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: all clean distclean
```